# What does the "Launch Application" window do when downloading software?

Tags: lubuntu, downloads

I'm running Lubuntu,and I want to download and install a free password generator called PWGEN from the Ubuntu Software Centre. However, when I click the download button on the following page: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/pwgen/
, a Launch Application dialog box opens in which I am prompted to choose the name of an application. What application is it referring to, why is this application needed, and where can I find it?

In contrast, when I download software from the Lubuntu Software Center, there's no application required. The software downloads and installs transparently.

==============

Reply to user297048

I found "apturl" but did not have to download it because it was already downloaded. However, I could not find "apt" in the list of applications. So, I could not go any further.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Menu > System Tools > Lubuntu Software Centre.

There download the software "AptUrl".

[image: AU]

Now, launch Firefox and goto Menu > Preferences.

[image: M]

Then, under Applications (tab) you will see "apt".

[image: A]

Click on "Always Ask", and then, "Use Other".

Now, navigate to Filesystem > usr > bin.

[image: U]

There select apturl and click on open.

Finally, close the Preferences window.

Now, every time you click on any apt link the apturl window will pop up and you will be able to install your software.

Hope! this helps. Thank You!

Comment: In my install of Lubuntu 17.04, there is no "Lubuntu Software Center."

Comment: @user297048 - `sudo apt-get install apturl`